# No module named 'cv2' even after successfully installing it using pip

Tags: python, opencv, terminal

I am working on ssd - tensor flow project. For which I have to use cv2.
I am able to import it in *Jupyter notebook* as well as in *terminal* too.

On running the following command

```
print cv2.__version__
```

I am getting output:-

```
3.4.1
```

which surely means its installed successfully. (I used `sudo pip install opencv-python` command to install and had tried `brew install` as well to resolve the issue) , but still when I run my example.py files using terminal commands. they are giving the following error

```
No module named 'cv2
```

I had tried every possibility (by searching for every related issue but still not able to resolve it). Please help.

Comment: run `import sys; print(sys.executable)` in both terminals (the one which is working and the other one) and compare. are they the same?

Comment: yes they are same both in terminal and in Jupyter notebook.Both gives result as /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Comment: Are you sure that pip version you installed is the same as the Python version that your machine is running?

Comment: Actually the problem arise when I run some python file from terminal. for example I have to run train.py using it but it gives error on the line at which opencv was imported.

Comment: I run the following command  pip --version and it gives pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7).. and I have only 2.7 python version installed on my machine.

Comment: using the working `cv2` import environment, `import cv2; print(cv2.__file__)`. Is this a path not accessible from terminal somehow?...

Comment: I think this is accessible from terminal. On running the following command it gives path :-    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so

Comment: Post the exactly same commands you run in both sittuations: (i) what are the steps you perform to `print cv2.version`; and (ii) how do you run your `example.py` script. Do you use `sudo` in any of them?

Comment: I used the following two commands to print cv2.version  1.  `python import cv2    cv2.__version__`.    2.`$ pkg-config --modversion opencv.`. and for running the example.py I just used cd to go to that directory and used `./examply.py` (that was what written in the guidelines for using that SSD project)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```